# How to import excel data into Toad 9.5 table

Tags: oracle, toad

How to import Excel data into Toad 9.5 Table

I have Toad for Oracle 9.5 and MS Excel 2007. I want to import Excel data into Oracle table using Toad.

Please let me know the steps, how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Look at using external tables on oracle.

Comment: Database -> Import -> Import table data

Answer (score 2):

try the following methods

**METHOD 1:** Click Tools → Import → Import Wizard. This window can be used to import data from various kinds of source files into a table.

**METHOD 2:** SQL*Loader You can use TOAD's interface to a program from Oracle called sqlloader. Save the Excel file as a comma-delimited (.csv) or tab-delimited (.txt) file. If your data has commas within a text field, save your file as tab-delimited.

Open DBA→Sql Loader Wizard

Choose "build a new control file". Next.

Click "Add". Choose your comma-delimited or tab-delimited file. Next.

Click "Add". Choose your table.

If you are loading a comma-delimited file, type a comma in the "all fields delimited by" combo box. If you are loading a tab-delimited file, select "TAB" from the "all fields delimited by" combo box. Next.

Choose a "load method" noting the following:

TRUNCATE will erase whatever is in the table before loading.

INSERT will insert data if table is empty but will return an error if table has any data in it.

APPEND will insert data without deleting any existing data. You might get duplicates this way but it's a good method if you're trying to get that last line that somehow got munged for some reason or another.

If your file has column headers in its first row, type a 1 in the skip box. Next.

Type a control file name in the control file name box. Next.

Choose either "execute now" to load the data now or "just build the control file" to build the .ctl file. Once you have the ctl file theoretically you don't even need TOAD, as you could just use sqlloader on any machine that has sqlloader and can connect to the database. But why would you want to. :)  I choose execute now.

Note: If you are working with Oracle 8.0 or earlier on a Windows 2000 or later OS, uncheck "Watch Progress"

Note: once you have a ctl file you can:

Choose DBA→Sql Loader Wizard

Choose "Use control file". Next.

Select your control file. Next.

Choose "execute now". Finish.

Answer (score 1):

Menu Database then Import and Import Table data.

You have to select the table where are you going to import and then, the more easy way, import from Clipboard (so before proceed to import just ctrl+c your cells in excel).

Usually I copy also the header row, it helps me in checking if columns are matched well.